# Including support and libraries for native interface error

Tags: codenameone

I am sorry to bother you again but it still does not work with this... The new error is :

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [{name=support-v4-25.0.0, ext=aar}] on DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.opentok.android', name='opentok-android-sdk', version='2.11.0', configuration='default'}.

(Here is the entire [Log](https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/6303a43d-c33c-4106-a510-b9b552ef2cce-1500031186135-error.txt))

In the library the properties file contains the following lines: (codenameone_library_required.properties)

```html
codename1.arg.java.version=8
codename1.arg.android.buildToolsVersion=25.0.0
codename1.arg.android.playServicesVersion=9.8.0
codename1.arg.android.supportv4Dep=compile 'com.android.support\:support-v4\:25.+'
codename1.arg.android.gradleDep= compile 'com.opentok.android\:opentok-android-sdk\:2.11.0'
```

The codenameone_library_appended.properties file is empty.

We included the aar files (support-v4-25.0.0.aar, appcompat-v7-25.0.0.aar and opentok-android-sdk-2.11.0.aar) in the library in the native/android.

We are out of ideas to try, can you please help us again?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those hints aren't for the inclusion of the AAR. That's unnecessary. Once you include those hints the support library should "just work" and including the AAR will become redundant since we already include it.

Answer (score 1):

We removed the aars, kept the one from opentok and added the support v7 arr and now it works ! Thank you very much !